# Azure AD B2C - Custom Provider for GitHub cannot get access token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I am setting up GitHub as a custom provider in Azure AD B2C using custom policies. I am able to get to the login page and successfully redirect back to the correct azure ad link, but a server error in Azure AD B2C always rejects the second part of OAUTH.

When I look at the app insights trace logs, it says "An invalid OAuth response was received" and "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: a" is encountered. Here is the policy provider I set up:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>github.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>GitHub</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="GitHub-OAUTH">
          <DisplayName>GitHub</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">github</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize</Item>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.github.com/user</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">My Client Id</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">user</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_GitHubSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="github.com" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

I wonder if the issue is that the access_token is not returned in a json? I stepped through all of the steps myself in postman, and the code was returned as a url parameter, and the access_token was returned in the body of the response like this:

```
access_token=<snip>&scope=user%3Aemail&token_type=bearer
```

Am I missing a metadata item in the custom provider to support this response? Or does this just not work in Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is because the access token response is encoded as a HTML form, rather than JSON.

Following is how to integrate with GitHub.

1) Add a claim type for the GitHub user identifier of type `long`:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="gitHubUserId">
  <DisplayName>GitHub User ID</DisplayName>
  <DataType>long</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

2) Add a claims transformation for converting from the GitHub user identifier of type `long` to the Azure AD B2C social user identifier of type `string`:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateAlternativeSecurityUserIdForGitHub" TransformationMethod="ConvertNumberToStringClaim">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="gitHubUserId" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

3) Add the technical profile for the GitHub OAuth flow:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="GitHub-OAUTH">
  <DisplayName>GitHub</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ProviderName">github.com</Item>
    <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize</Item>
    <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpBinding">GET</Item>
    <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://api.github.com/user</Item>
    <Item Key="client_id">Insert the client identifier</Item>
    <Item Key="scope">user</Item>
    <Item Key="UserAgentForClaimsExchange">CPIM-Basic/{tenant}/{policy}</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_GitHubSecret" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="gitHubUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="github.com" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityUserIdForGitHub" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SSOSession-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Chris, thanks for the response! I'm able to see in app insights that the claims response is coming back from GitHub, but it's still giving an internal server error during the ValidateApiResponseHandler phase (and then it goes to NoOpHandler before returning the error): "A self-asserted send response has failed with reason 'Internal Server Error'."
I put the original policy name in the UserAgentForClaimsExchange field: CPIM-Basic/<tenant>/B2C_1A_signup_signin. Is that the correct policy to refer to?

Comment: What does UserAgentForClaimsExchange mean?

Comment: You shouldn't replace any of the {tenant} or {policy} tokens. The Azure AD B2C engine will replace them.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification! The server error I was running into had to do with the email claim not being able to handle "email": "Null" during validation. I removed the email claim and your solution was working great. Thanks so much!

Comment: Excellent! @X.Ou For the email claim to be issued by GitHub, the GitHub user must have a public email address, otherwise it issues "null".

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Yes, that makes sense. Unfortunately, it is currently causing internal server error for Azure AD B2C anytime email is "null", so I can't use email claims even for users with public emails in case someone does not have a public email. Do you know of a workaround for this? I was trying to see if it could be accomplished with some sort of claim transformation, but I wasn't able to find documentation on it.