# Azure AD b2c: Adding third party oAuth providers

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

As a service provider, I need to integrate third party oAuth providers beyond what is currently available in the portal. How can I do that? Any pointers will be helpful. If it is not supported, is it in the product road map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you have to create custom policies to integrate with other OpenID Connect and OAuth identity providers, such as [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom) and [GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732652/azure-ad-b2c-custom-provider-for-github-cannot-get-access-token/47743805#47743805).

The "[Add support for a generic OpenID Connect Identity Provider](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/17699680-add-support-for-a-generic-openid-connect-identity)" feedback item indicates development has been started for the built-in support of any OpenID Connect or OAuth provider.